# How to append a method to my button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a function called getRandomColor() and I want to apply this method to my button in the HTML doc. So, when you click the button it changes the entire body's color.

This is the javascript code:

```
function getRandomColor() {
    var letters = '0123456789ABCDEF'.split('');
    var color = '#';
    for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++ ) {
        color += letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)];
    }
    return color; 
  }
```

This is the HTML code for the button and my attempt to apply the JS code:

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-6-xs">
          <button onclick="getRandomColor()"id="quotes"type="button" class="right-btn pull-right btn btn-success">Get Quotes</button>
        </div>
```

Right away, I can tell that clicking the button won't change the document's color. I was thinking of adding this code to the getRandomColor() method:

```
document.body.style.background = color;
```

However, it still doesn't change the document color.

Comment: try this using .css method, then put the css code inside

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually the code you submitted, does seem to work, the only thing you might need to do is at the end of the function, apply the color to the DOM

```js
function getRandomColor() {
    var letters = '0123456789ABCDEF'.split('');
    var color = '#';
    for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++ ) {
        color += letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)];
    }
  document.body.style.background = color;
}
```

```html
<body>
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-6-xs">
          <button onclick="getRandomColor()"id="quotes"type="button" class="right-btn pull-right btn btn-success">Get Quotes</button>
        </div>
</div>
</body>
```